# Android - Executing a custom listview in a custom dialog properly

Tags: android, listview, dialog

I have an application where I would want to display a custom list view consisting of two textViews inside a custom dialog box in android. So far, I'm having a difficult time figuring out how to connect the two and generate the contents of the dialog box.

I tried to follow custom listView tutorials with the hopes of just setting the dialog adapter to it but to no avail.

So far, this is what I have so far:

This is list_row_dialog.xml, the layout for the row containing two textviews:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="50dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dip" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/unit"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:typeface="sans" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/quantity"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:textColor="#343434"
    android:textSize="12sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And here is the dialog_main.xml file, the layout file that I want the dialog box to use, it's basically a listView.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/custom_list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And here's CustomListAdapterDialog.java, I'm not sure if I even need to use this to display data on the dialog box:

```
public class CustomListAdapterDialog extends BaseAdapter {

private ArrayList<ItemClass> listData;

private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

public CustomListAdapterDialog(Context context, ArrayList<ItemClass> listData) {
    this.listData = listData;
    layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return listData.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return listData.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row_dialog, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.unitView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.unit);
        holder.quantityView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.quantity);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.unitView.setText(listData.get(position).getVariant().toString());
    holder.quantityView.setText(listData.get(position).getUnit().toString());

    return convertView;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView unitView;
    TextView quantityView;
}

}
```

Initially, I tried this code to display the dialog box:

```
private void showDialog(){
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_main);


    dialog.show();
}
```

But it only shows, one blank row, it is very clear that I am not populating it properly.

Any ideas anyone? Also, I can populate the dialog boxes in the `showDialog()` function since I also have the data I want to populate with in the same java class.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Are you doing the following? You will need to inflate the layout file `dialog_main`, find the `ListView`, set an adapter and an OnItemClickListener for it. After this, you can use the dialog's `setContentView(View)` method to get the list to display.

```
private void showDialog(){

    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);

    View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_main, null);

    ListView lv = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.custom_list);

    // Change MyActivity.this and myListOfItems to your own values
    CustomListAdapterDialog clad = new CustomListAdapterDialog(MyActivity.this, myListOfItems);

    lv.setAdapter(clad);

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(........);

    dialog.setContentView(view);

    dialog.show();

}
```

By the way, your adapter looks alright. It isn't working because you're not giving it anything to work on.

Comment: Finally I get it to work! Thank you so much sir! I was stuck in this task for around 3 days.

Comment: How to dismiss when click on item. I wrote like `dialog.dismiss();` but its not working.