# Android - Set TextColor ListItem on an AlertDialog with list programatically

Tags: java, android, dialog, android-alertdialog

I have an AlertDialog where a user must choose between several options. The default color scheme for this is white text on a darkgrey background. In the App users can configure their own color which are suppose to match with white. Changing the background to white isn't the issue, but I cannot set the textcolor of the items.

I was looking for something like `dialog.getItems.setTextColor([usercolor]);`, but I haven't found a solution for it. Below my code for building the dialog.

```
    tvRekening.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(a);
                builder.setTitle("Title")
                        .setItems(values, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                // The 'which' argument contains the index position
                                // of the selected item
                                setRekeningView(which);
                            }
                        });
                AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(ContextCompat.getColor(a, R.color.white)));
                dialog.show();
            }
        });
```

To further illustrate the issue:

The default color scheme:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/nMKAA.png

Changing the background color to white makes the text unreadable (because it's still white).
https://i.stack.imgur.com/PEABc.png

EDIT:
I understand I can create a custom adapter for this. But creating an Adapter only for editing the text color of the items seems a bit of an overkill. If someone knows a solution without going through the trouble of creating an adapter, it would be appreciated. If not i'll close the question in a while.

Comment: For changing color of text need to create custom Adapter with layout then pass it to setAdapter method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to create custom dialog like this:

```
Dialog d =new Dialog(context);
d.setContentView(R.layout.dialog); 
ListView l=((ListView )d.findViewById(R.id.list));
```

see this link [Android - Executing a custom listview in a custom dialog properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17914714/android-executing-a-custom-listview-in-a-custom-dialog-properly)

Comment: Creating an adapter is overkill for this in my opinion. I'm looking for an easier solution.

Comment: As disappointed as I am, I'm gonna mark this as correct, as it seems there is no other way.

Answer (score 1):

create new theme in styles.xml

```
<style name="MyDialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="android:background">@color/alertDialogDark</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorAlertDialogListItem">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

you need to change android:textColorAlertDialogListItem to whatever color you like

And in code write this

```
AlertDialog.Builder orderByBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this, R.style.MyDialogTheme);
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is created a long time ago, but I had the same problem and by looking into the AlertController class I found there is a way to set a viewAdapter (so you don't have to create a ListView yourself as the current accepted answer in 11/2023 suggests).

[image]

(Check out Close Ties app which is a messaging app for Close Ties at closeties.com)

```
     val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(activity)
     // instead of setItems use setAdapter
     builder.setAdapter(ColorListAdapter(colorAlertItemsList, colorsList, WeakReference(this)), DialogInterface.OnClickListener { dialog, which ->
         if (which == 0) {
         }
     })
```

Creating a ListAdapter subclass is easy like:

```
class ColorListAdapter(val display_text_list: MutableList<String>,
                               val color_list: MutableList<Int>,
                               private val messagingDetailFragment: WeakReference<MessagingDetailFragment>
) :
    ListAdapter {

    override fun isEmpty(): Boolean {
        return display_text_list.size == 0
    }
    override fun getView(position: Int, view: View?, viewGroup: ViewGroup?): View {
        val rootView: ConstraintLayout;
        if (view == null) {
            rootView = LayoutInflater.from(messagingDetailFragment.get()!!.activity as AppCompatActivity)
                .inflate(R.layout.fragment_messaging_detail_color_alert_dialog_cell, null) as ConstraintLayout
        } else {
            rootView = view as ConstraintLayout
        }
        val textView = rootView.findViewById<AppCompatButton>(R.id.textView)
        textView.text = display_text_list[position];
        textView.setTextColor(color_list[position])
        return rootView;
    }

    override fun registerDataSetObserver(p0: DataSetObserver?) {
    }

    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
        return 0
    }

    override fun getItem(p0: Int): Any {
        return display_text_list[p0]
    }

    override fun getViewTypeCount(): Int {
        return 1;
    }

    override fun isEnabled(p0: Int): Boolean {
        return true
    }

    override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long = position.toLong()

    override fun hasStableIds(): Boolean {
        return true
    }

    override fun areAllItemsEnabled(): Boolean {
        return true
    }

    override fun unregisterDataSetObserver(p0: DataSetObserver?) {
    }

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return display_text_list.size
    }
}
```

And the xml for the view could be like:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:text="Retry"
        android:textColor="@color/tintColor"
        android:background="@drawable/selected_bottom_sheet_button_background_line"
        android:textSize="20.5sp"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```