# Build Alert Dialog with a List

Tags: android, arrays, string, set, android-alertdialog

I'm trying to build an AlertDialog with a list on my Android app.
This is code I'm using to build the dialog:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(HomeActivity.this);
builder.setTitle("Pick a branch to navigate to:");
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
adapter.addAll(branches);
builder.setAdapter(adapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        Intent locationIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NavigationActivity.class);
        locationIntent.putExtra("branch", which);
        startActivity(locationIntent);
    }
});
builder.show();
```

Just to make things clear: `branches` is a `Set<String>`.

On the log from the intented activity, I get a message saying:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
```

I get the exception above for a command uses a converted `Set<String>` to a `String[]`, which is I think why the AlertDialog is empty.

How can I solve it and show an AlertDialog with a list contains items from `Set<String>`?

Comment: Your Set is empty.
Can you please show the code of Set initializing and adding items to the Set

Comment: Make sure set of branches is not empty before adding it to adapter!

Comment: @VishalChhodwani, the set is not empty, since I initialize it in the same block as another set with the same code and the other one works great.

Comment: @DeepakS.Gavkar The same comment to you too.

Comment: Check out the answer of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17914714/android-executing-a-custom-listview-in-a-custom-dialog-properly

Answer (score 0):

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Schedule Post");
String[] items={"Item 1","Item 2","Item 3"};
alertDialogBuilder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

        }
    });
AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
alertDialog.show();
```

Comment: Please explain your answer as to why OP should try your answer and what actually wrong in question/code which OP has posted.